# Is a PopUp the right thing to display two imagebuttons in order to give the user a choice between two options?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

Hello I'm programming an App (a game) with Xamarin and I would like to implement the following:
When the -+4 Card is chosen a PopUp should appear which forces the youser to choose his final answer. Therefore this PopUp should contain two ImageButtons with a +4 and a -4 card on it. I am wondering what the best solution is for this as the best thing I came up with was a CustomPopUp.

[image: Here an image for illustration:]

Comment: "best" is a matter of opinion and not on-topic for SO.  But a popup certainly sounds like a reasonable option.

Comment: Alright. Thank you! I'm just not familiar the amount of possibilities Xamarin offers haha so i thought I might ask first...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/

Comment: for custom popups, consider using https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: @Jason thank you thats what I'm searching for !